# Apostrophe CMS: Get piece data in nested join (joinByArray – joinByOne)

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm having problems with getting data of the piece from nested join: `joinByArray` – `joinByOne`. I tried to use the projection filters in joins and to omit them – it does not work (in different ways, but the result is the same – no joined piece data).

Here is my setup. I have defined two pieces:

Author:

```
extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
name: 'author',
// ...
addFields: [
{
  name: 'photo',
  label: 'Photo',
  required: true,
  type: 'singleton',
  widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
  options: {
    limit: [ 1 ]
  }
},
// ...
```

Publication:

```
extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
name: 'publication',
// ...
addFields: [
{
  name: '_author',
  label: 'Author',
  type: 'joinByOne',
  withType: 'author',
  idField: 'authorId',
  filters: {
    projection: {
      slug: 1,
      type: 1,
      tags: 1,
      title: 1,
      photo: 1
    }
  }
},
// ...
```

Then I created a Publications Page like this:

```
extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-pages',
name: 'publications-page',
// ...
addFields: [
{
  name: '_featured',
  label: 'Featured Publications',
  type: 'joinByArray',
  withType: 'publication',
  idsField: 'featuredIds',
  filters: {
    projection: {
      slug: 1,
      title: 1,
      type: 1,
      // ...
      _author: 1
    }
  },
  relationship: [
    // ...
  ]
},
// ...
```

As you can see `_featured` is the featured publications list those are supposed to be displayed on the top of the page followed by the list on other publications. I need all the data to display them correctly, including Author's name (`title`) and photo.

The thing is that in Nunjucks template I got:

- `authorId` only if I use `projection` for `_featured` join
- no signs of Author data at all if I omit `projection` for `_featured` join

The general list of publications (available through `data.pieces` in Nunjucks `index.html` template) is PERFECT and contains all the data. While `data.page._featured` does NOT.

**MY QUESTION: is there a way to tell Apostrophe CMS to fetch data from nested joins like those above? So to get Author piece data for "featured" Publications on Publications Page?**

*I like this setup, and I'd prefer to keep it this way. But if I need to change something (e.g. use `singleton` instead on `joinByOne`), I may try it as well.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add `withJoins: true` to your `_featured` join configuration